# Scraping names from NBA website with jsoup

Tags: css, jsoup

I am trying to scrape the players' names from the left column (under the search bar) from NBA website https://www.nba.com/players, all the names are in `span` tags, but for reasons I cannot select them at all with https://try.jsoup.org/

The closest I have come is to do `a`, but then the name gets mixed up with other information as well. If I do `span` then I only get the information without the name. `div > span` gives the same thing - no name.

Comment: Hi that's interesting, perhaps try `p.nba-player-index__name`  (to catch `<p class="nba-player-index__name">Bam<br>Adebayo</p>`)

Comment: It only can get 60 first name unfortunately :( I must scroll down if I want to get more names

Comment: can't you just fetch from here? [https://www.nba.com/players/active_players.json](https://www.nba.com/players/active_players.json). Gives you all 497 active players.

Comment: Oh wow! I have not thought about that. Thank you!